# Can you tell me what species of insect this is?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Verona, Italy. 
Today I found this black insect and I don't know what species it is. My mom claims it's a kind of mint but I don't think so.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Biology.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn your first badge. Also, what do you mean by "mint"? How's that called in Italian?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a horsefly (family Tabanidae, in Italian "tafani"), maybe [*Tabanus bromius*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabanus_bromius) but I'm not sure. If it's so, be careful: they bite and their bite is painful. [Here](http://home.bt.com/lifestyle/health/health-concerns/horsefly-bites-what-to-do-if-you-get-bitten-this-summer-11364198613492) you can find some quick suggestions about horseflies and their bite.

However, as you live in a city, don't worry too much: as the female horseflies feed on horse and cattle blood, they are normally present in the countryside, so those that you saw are exceptions more than the norm!

Comment: The eyes are a bit far apart to be a horsefly; I'm leaning toward Robber Fly (Asilidae) or Stiletto Fly (Therevidae), but can't be sure from the photo (and given how old the question is, I suspect that the model is no longer available for additional photos).

Comment: It's obviously not a horsefly